# Image-processing filters using decorator pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, image

This is a follow-up question of [this other one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135754/image-processing-filters-using-decorator-pattern-in-python-3), where I was trying to use the Decorator Pattern in a Python example. I figured, that Java might be a better language for this exercise, so I ported my implementation.
While I appreciate any suggestion or remark related to the code below, I am first and foremost looking for advice related to the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). As an image processing library, I used [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html).

### The implementation of the pattern

**Image.java**

```
import marvin.image.MarvinImage;

public interface Image {
    MarvinImage getInternalImage();
    Image getParent();
}
```

**BaseImage.java**

```
import marvin.image.MarvinImage;

public class BaseImage implements Image {
    private MarvinImage imageObject;

    public BaseImage(MarvinImage imageObject) {
        this.imageObject = imageObject;
    }

    @Override
    public MarvinImage getInternalImage() {
        return imageObject.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public Image getParent() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

**ImageDecorator.java**

```
public abstract class ImageDecorator implements Image {

    private Image image;

    public ImageDecorator(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public Image getParent() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

**BlurFilter.java**

```
import marvin.image.MarvinImage;
import marvin.plugin.MarvinImagePlugin;
import marvin.util.MarvinPluginLoader;

public class BlurFilter extends ImageDecorator {

    private MarvinImagePlugin imagePlugin;

    public BlurFilter(Image image) {
        super(image);
        imagePlugin = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.blur.gaussianBlur.jar");
    }

    @Override
    public MarvinImage getInternalImage() {
        MarvinImage image = getParent().getInternalImage().clone();
        imagePlugin.process(image, image);
        image.update();
        return image;
    }
```

**ImageFlipper.java**

```
import marvin.image.MarvinImage;
import marvin.plugin.MarvinImagePlugin;
import marvin.util.MarvinPluginLoader;

public class ImageFlipper extends ImageDecorator {

    private MarvinImagePlugin imagePlugin;

    public ImageFlipper(Image image) {
        super(image);
        imagePlugin = MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.transform.flip.jar");
    }

    @Override
    public MarvinImage getInternalImage() {
        MarvinImage image = getParent().getInternalImage().clone();
        imagePlugin.process(image, image);
        image.update();
        return image;
    }

}
```

### Usage example

Parts relevant for the Decorator pattern have been marked with (1), (2), (3), (4) and (5). The code for setting up the GUI is based on the [Marvin Tutorial](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/tutorials/02_firstApplication/firstApplication.html) (and as I said, it is not the focus of this question).

```
// imports omitted for brevity

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private JPanel  panelBottom; 

    private JButton buttonFlip,
                    buttonGaussianBlur,
                    buttonUndo,
                    buttonCommit;

    private MarvinImagePanel imagePanel;
    private Image image;

    public Main() { 
        super("First Application");

        // Create Graphical Interface 
        buttonFlip = new JButton("Flip");
        buttonFlip.addActionListener(this); 
        buttonGaussianBlur = new JButton("Gaussian");
        buttonGaussianBlur.addActionListener(this); 
        buttonUndo = new JButton("Undo");
        buttonUndo.addActionListener(this); 
        buttonCommit = new JButton("Commit");
        buttonCommit.addActionListener(this); 

        panelBottom = new JPanel();
        panelBottom.add(buttonFlip);
        panelBottom.add(buttonGaussianBlur);
        panelBottom.add(buttonUndo);
        panelBottom.add(buttonCommit); 

        // ImagePanel 
        imagePanel = new MarvinImagePanel();

        Container l_c = getContentPane();
        l_c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        l_c.add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        l_c.add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        MarvinImage marvinImage = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./lena.gif");
        image = new BaseImage(marvinImage);     // <== (1)

        refreshImage();

        setSize(marvinImage.getWidth() + 50, marvinImage.getHeight() + 100);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getSource() == buttonFlip) {
            image = new ImageFlipper(image);  // <== (2)
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == buttonGaussianBlur) {
            image = new BlurFilter(image);    // <== (3)
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == buttonUndo){
            image = image.getParent();        // <== (4)
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == buttonCommit){
            image = new BaseImage(image.getInternalImage()); // <== (5)
        }
        refreshImage();
    }

    private void refreshImage() {
        imagePanel.setImage(image.getInternalImage());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main t = new Main(); 
        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This method:

```
@Override
public MarvinImage getInternalImage() {
    MarvinImage image = getParent().getInternalImage().clone();
    imagePlugin.process(image, image);
    image.update();
    return image;
}
```

Is an exact duplicate in two classes that have the same super class. It should be in that super class.

Same goes for this variable:

```
private MarvinImagePlugin imagePlugin
```

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to perform the image processing in the getter method and not the constructor. If I were using an image library, I'd suspect that creating the filter (which with the decorator pattern is synonymous with applying it to an image) would do the heavy lifting of the image processing necessary and not in some method that does retrieve the internal image data.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Especially regarding the last paragraph: in fact adding more and more filters makes the refreshing slower and slower, since each time *all* the previous stages are recalculated as well. I might improve this in the future :)